# What PowerShell version introduced a given cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm putting `#Requires -Version` at the top of my script, but need to figure out what version I require. I was hoping to query what version of PowerShell introduced each of the cmdlets I call. But I don't see that in the `Get-Help -verbose` output for one of the cmdlets. I didn't find a canonical web page listing for it.

Anyone know if there's a standard way to look up what version of PowerShell introduced a particular cmdlet? Or, is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I usually check the msdn documentation for a given cmdlet (the one with the arguments and types, not the useless "Using foo command" pages), and check the versions drop down to see where it starts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, as far as I am aware the "standard" way to look this up is to read MSDN. :-) You can get to the relevant page pretty easily using the `-Online` switch for `Get-Help`, for example:

```
Get-Help -Name "Get-DscConfiguration" -Online
```

Another approach might be to fire up **powershell.exe** using the `-Version` switch to set a specific version, e.g. **powershell.exe -Version 2** then use the `Get-Command` cmdlet to see if your cmdlets are listed or not.

---

I have enjoyed myself! Here is some code that seems to work OK parsing a script and then working out if the commands are valid cmdlets in different PS versions. At this point, it doesn't seem that "1.0" or "5.0" are supported by the `-PSVersion` switch on `Start-Job` though.

```
param(
  $file = 'C:\scripts\PowerShell\Toolkit\Get-PSVersionCompatibility.ps1'
)

New-Variable tokens
New-Variable parseerrors
$p = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($file,[ref]$tokens,[ref]$parseerrors)
$Commands = $tokens | ?{$_.TokenFlags -contains "CommandName"} | Sort -Unique | Select Value

$ScriptBlock = {
  param($PSVersion,$Commands)

  $Output = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{PSVersion = $PSVersion}


  foreach($Command in $Commands) {
    if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Command.Value)){continue}

    if(Get-Command | ?{$_.Name -eq $Command.Value}) {
      $Available = $true
    } else {
      $Available = $false
    }

    $Output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $($Command.Value) -Value $Available
  }

  return $Output
}

$Results = @()

foreach($PSVersion in 2..4) {
  $job = Start-Job -PSVersion "$PSVersion.0" -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $PSVersion,$Commands

  Wait-Job $job | Out-Null
  $Results += (Receive-Job $job | Select PSVersion,*-*)
  Remove-Job $job
}

$Results | FT -AutoSize

Remove-Variable tokens
Remove-Variable parseerrors
```

[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)

Comment: Unfortunately, since the new "docs.micrsosoft.." were published I can not find the "introduced in version" anymore... Whatever, your solution is really powerful. THANKS! I have added and extended it to the open source library, if it is not okay just tell me: https://github.com/AstralisSomnium/PowerShell-No-Library-Just-Functions

Comment: Go for it. No problem.